# Sending List of objects in c# web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have the following two objects:

```
public class Dog
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
} 

public class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
  public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

Now, in the server side, I build a mix List of Person and Dog, and I would like to return this List to the client via web-service (asmx).

The order is important, and eventually my list will hold more types.

How can I return a list of mixed object in web-service?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't return 2 lists? One for Dog, second for Person.

Comment: then you need to create another class which contains list<Dog> and List<Person> as two properties

Comment: just wrap it in a class such as ResponseResult and send it back

Comment: What is your technology? WCF?

Comment: No. it is web-service

Comment: It smells like a list of dogs and owners. If this is the case, why not add the dogs to the persons? And if the "other types" will be different pet types, then create a pet class and each pet (dog, cat, whatever) inherits from it, so the Person can have a list of Pets, each of different type.

Comment: Thank Gusman, this is not the situation. The objects have nothing in common.

Comment: what you mean for "web-services"? wcf? web-api?

Comment: .asmx  web-service

Comment: You may think about generics, but generics have no meaning for ASMX.

Another idea could be using JSON and trying to resolve them at run-time as soon as you get a request, but this options looks a bit hacky.


I would just go for creating two different routes.

Comment: what do you mean that "mix List"?

Comment: "mix list" is a list that contains both Person type and Dog type (and maybe in the future more other types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create new class that encapsulate your many classes

```
public class Dog : MyClass
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
} 

public class Person : MyClass
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
  public string ID {get;set;}
} 

public class NewClass
{
    public enum OBJType { 
       Dog,Person
    } // like a constant for specific object type
    public Dog D_Dog { get; set;  }
    public Person D_Person { get; set; }
    public OBJType Type { get; set; } 
    public int seq { get; set; }

}
```

Then it should be use like this

```
        //At Server
        List<NewClass> newList = new List<NewClass>();
        NewClass Item1 = new NewClass();
        Item1.D_Dog =  new Dog() { Name = "Woof", Age = 3 };
        Item1.seq = 1;
        Item1.Type =  NewClass.OBJType.Dog;
        newList.Add(Item1);

        NewClass Item2 = new NewClass();
        Item2.D_Person = new Person() { Name = "John", City = "TPP" , ID =111 };
        Item2.seq = 2;
        Item2.Type = NewClass.OBJType.Person;
        newList.Add(Item2);


        //At Client
        List<NewClass> newList = //..get form webservice 

         foreach (var Item in newList)
        {
            if (Item.Type == NewClass.OBJType.Dog)
            {
                // using Item.D_Dog;
            }
            else {
                // using Item.D_Person

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro at C# so excuse if its not the most efficient.

1st class ie Person.cs

```
public class Person : MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

2nd Class ie Dog.cs

```
public class Dog : MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The inherited class ie MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Notice I have added a field Type to differentiate between objects in the program consuming the webservice. You can improve this with enums for type.

The Example function to return the data.

```
public List<MyClass> returnData()
        {


            List<MyClass> returningdata = new List<MyClass>();

            Person pers = new Person();
            pers.City = "NELSPRUIT";
            pers.Name = "TED";
            pers.ID = "5502226585665";
            pers.Type = "PERSON";

            returningdata.Add(pers);

            Dog doggy = new Dog();
            doggy.Name = "Tiny";
            doggy.Age = 2;
            doggy.Type = "DOG";

            returningdata.Add(doggy);

            return returningdata;
        }
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I am in the client side, I see person properties in dog type, and dog properties in person type.

Comment: Jip, that's the reason I have added the Type property so the client side can differentiate between objects. Do not know how to mix a list without doing it this way.How else will one differentiate between objects in the same list?

Comment: You can always check the Type property in the client side and cast it to the specified type object. So split the MyClass properties take Dog properties and put it in class Dog and do the same with person.. but still inherit from Myclass. Then in the client side using the Type property cast it to the correct object.